# Приостановка (не завершение Task) из другого таска

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Есть ли способы сделать ПРИОСТАНОВКУ тасков (не завершение), вызванную из другого таска?

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
           {
               await Task.Run(() => FullReg());
               await Task.Delay(5000);
               if (checkBox1.Checked)
               {
                   if (i % proxyswitch == 0 && i != 0)
                   {
                       //Task.WaitAll(); -- ТУТ ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ ПРИОСТАНОВКА ВСЕХ ТАСКОВ
                       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\HMA! Pro VPN\bin\HMA! Pro VPN.exe", "-changeip");
                       await Task.Delay(10000);
                   }
               }
           }
           while(int.Parse(CountFailedAccLabel.Text) + int.Parse(CountFailedAccLabel.Text) != count)
           {
               await Task.Delay(proxyswitch*5000);
               await Task.Run(() => ChangeIPHMAButton_Click(sender, e));
               await Task.Delay(10000);
               //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\HMA! Pro VPN\bin\HMA! Pro VPN.exe", "-changeip");
           }
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы не можете остановить другой код просто так. Этот код должен сотрудничать. 
Например, вы можете взвести булев флаг, который должен проверяться параллельно бегущим кодом, или залочить общий объект, который ваш параллельный код должен время от времени пытаться залочить от отпустить.

Comment: Кстати, в вашем коде _очень_ много `Task.Delay`, что, вероятно, означает проблемы архитектурного характера.

Answer (score 0):

Уже сам нашел делается через lock

```
private object syncObj = new object();
public async void TestProxy()
{
    for (int i = 5; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + " task started!");

        TaskRegSimsms(i);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        if (i == 5)
        {                
            lock (syncObj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LOCKED!!!");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }        
}

public async void TaskRegSimsms(int x)
{
    lock (syncObj) { }
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 1 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 2 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 3 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    lock (syncObj) { }
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 4 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    lock (syncObj) { }
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 5 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 6 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 7 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 8 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 9 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + 10 + " of " + x + " task");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Возможно `task.Join();` поможет.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?